# What's the correct word to complete this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Whilst doing my homework, I realized that I couldn't choose an answer for the following sentence problem:

> But when household gadgets break down, ⸻ are carried out by 82 percent of husbands.

A. repairs
B. fixings
C. fittings
D. amenments

I am sure that C and D are wrong. Is it A or B?

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Must be A the rest just don't make sense.

Comment: you mean A is ok?

Comment: Yes, A is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

"A: repairs" is the right answer. In American English, *fixings* usually means the accompanying side dishes that customarily go with a meal, as in "a steak dinner with all the fixings." In the dialect of my home region, *fixings* can also mean the accessories or parts used to assemble something mechanical, such as a clock. The other two choices are not suitable at all in this context.